# How to uninstall AWSPowerShell/AWS.Tools module from Powershell?

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, aws-powershell

First steps in Powershell. I can not remove / uninstall `AWSPowerShell`  module from AWS installed modules.
`Get-Module -Name AWSPowerShell,AWSPowerShell.NetCore,AWS.Tools.Common -ListAvailable` showing as follows:

```
    Directory: C:\Users\user\Documents\PowerShell\Modules

ModuleType Version    PreRelease Name                                PSEdition ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ---------- ----                                --------- ----------------
Binary     4.1.14.0              AWS.Tools.Common                    Core,Desk {Clear-AWSHistory, Set-AWSHistoryConfiguration, Initialize-AWSDefaultConfi…

    Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\AWS Tools\PowerShell

ModuleType Version    PreRelease Name                                PSEdition ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ---------- ----                                --------- ----------------
Binary     3.3.509.0             AWSPowerShell                       Desk
```

Whem I'm trying to uninstall it via `Uninstall-Module -Name AWSPowerShell` I'm getting error:

```
    Uninstall-Package: C:\program files\powershell\7\Modules\PowerShellGet\PSModule.psm1:12733
 Line |
12733 |  …        $null = PackageManagement\Uninstall-Package @PSBoundParameters
      |                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      | No match was found for the specified search criteria and module names 'AWSPowerShell'.
```

Question - how can i get rid of this one?

Comment: You should just be able to delete the folder entirely

Comment: Was thinking that it is not valid / recomended way. Did the trick, thank you.

Answer (score 10):

You need to simply delete it. If you want to do it via PowerShell, you can do something like this:

```
Get-Module -Name <ModuleName> -ListAvailable | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ModuleBase | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to Install the `AWSPowerShell` Module you need to place the folder inside

```
C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules
```

after that you can execute the following command to install the module:

```
Import-Module AWSPowerShell
```

Now `AWSPowerShell` should be installed on the client.

If you want to remove `AWSPowerShell` you need to execute the following command:

```
Remove-Module AWSPowerShell
```

Once the module is removed you can delete the folder:

```
C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\AWSPowerShell
```

More information on those commands can be found in the Microsoft Wiki:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/import-module?view=powershell-7.2

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/remove-module?view=powershell-7.2