# Install-Package : The following commands are already available on this system

Tags: powershell, aws-powershell

When I try to install AWSPowerShell, I am getting the following error:

> PackageManagement\Install-Package : The following commands are already available on this system:'Clear-AWSCredentials,Clear-AWSDefaults,Confirm-EC2EndpointConnection,Confirm-EC2ReservedInstancesExchangeQuote,Confirm-EC2TransitGatewayPeeringAttachment,Confirm-EC2TransitGatewayVpcAttachment,Confirm-EC2VpcPeeringConnection,Edit-EC2Hosts,.........

Screenshot:
[image]

How can I find out which modules to uninstall in order to fix the error?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to uninstall AWS.Tools, and after reading [How to uninstall AWSPowerShell/AWS.Tools module from Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68519677/how-to-uninstall-awspowershell-module-from-powershell), I found it in the folder `c:\Users\sashoalm\OneDrive\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\AWS.Tools.Common\`